# Rebuild permissions needed after installation from profile

Tags: installation-profiles

Once solved this issue:
[How to define settings from an install profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149730/how-to-define-settings-from-an-install-profile/149837#149837)

I would like to skip the Error Message I get on first load of the application:

```
Message d'erreur
Les permissions d'accès au contenu doivent être reconstruites. Reconstruire les permissions.
```

To do so, I've created a task to perform the function 
    node_access_rebuild(FALSE);

```
function genius_install_tasks(&$install_state) {
  $tasks['genius_settings'] = array(
      'display' => FALSE,
      'type' => 'batch',
      'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
  );

  $tasks['link_taxonomy_menu'] = array(
      'display' => FALSE,
      'type' => 'batch',
      'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
  );

  $tasks['rebuild_permissions'] = array(
      'display' => FALSE,
      'type' => 'batch',
      'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
  );

  return $tasks;

}
```

But it seems to don't be enough.In fact, I set a message that I can't see, so I think this task maybe is not being perform.

```
function rebuild_permissions() {
    // Rebuild permissions
    node_access_rebuild(FALSE);
    // This message is set at the end of the node_access_rebuild
    // Keep here to ensure this task has been made
    drupal_set_message(t('Content permissions have been rebuilt.'));

}
```

I am going to try to change the type of the task to normal.
**EDIT: This change doesn't solve the problem**

Mindwhile, appreciate reader, do you have any advice to do the rebuild permissions at the end of the installation correctly?

Thanks for the reading.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems as it is done from the hook_install.